# Unable to change color of first text box in every row of table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the background color of first text box in every row in a table and using below code for same purpose.
Somehow it does not seem to be working. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:text:first").css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

<tr>
<th>text1</th>
<td id="A7x1_1"><input type="text"></td>
<td id="A7x2_1"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>text2</th>
<td id="A7x1_2"><input type="text"></td>
<td id="A7x2_2"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>text3</th>
<td id="A7x1_3"><input type="text"></td>
<td id="A7x2_3"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$("tr input:first-child").css('background-color','#C0C0C0');` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** selector with `.find()` to get `input` descendants.

```
$('tr').find(':text:first').css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CL7F4/2/)**

`$("tr:text:first")` in your code, finds `tr` with `:text`*(type="text")* which is invalid.

`<tr>` does not have `:text`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you can't get jQuery to work, it would be simple enough to add a class to the first table cell in each table row and style it that way, forgoing the time it would take to load jQuery(if that is an issue, as I have sometimes found it to be).